# Потеряла строку кода в компоненте Битрикс

Tags: php, битрикс

Всем привет. В Битрикс, в компоненте вызова news.list, element_list_1 случайно затерла строчку кода, и никак не могу вспомнить что там было. В результате пропала навигация по страницам, перестали выводится заголовки с настроек SEO у разделов, также пропал вывод элементов на подразделах и пропал в редактировании news.list. [image: введите сюда описание изображения] Вот код

```
<?if( !defined("B_PROLOG_INCLUDED") || B_PROLOG_INCLUDED!==true ) die();?>
<?include_once(__DIR__."/../include_filter.php");?>

<?if($isAjax == "N"):?>

<?
$frame = new \Bitrix\Main\Page\FrameHelper('catalog-elements-block');
$frame->begin();
$frame->setAnimation(true);
?> 
<?endif;?>
<?if($isAjax == "Y"):?>


<?$APPLICATION->RestartBuffer();?>

<?endif;?>

<?if($isAjax == "N"):?>

<div class="ajax_load <?=$display;?>">

<?endif;?>
```

```
<div class="sort_display_block"<?=($isAjax == "Y" ? ' style="display:none;"' : '')?>>


<?@include_once(__DIR__.'/../landing_top.php');?>
<?@include_once(__DIR__.'/../include_sort.php');?>

</div>
<?$upperDisplay = $display ? strtoupper($display): 'TABLE';?>
<!--тут строка-->
<?@include_once($sViewElementsTemplate.'.php');?>
<?@include_once(__DIR__.'/../bottom_description.php');?>
```

```
<?if($isAjax == "N"):?>
</div>

<?$frame->end();?>
<?else:?>
<?die();?>
<?endif;?>


<?if($arSeoItem):?>

<?if($arSeoItem):?>
<?if(!isset($arSeoItem["IPROPERTY_VALUES"]))
{
$ipropValues = new 
\Bitrix\Iblock\InheritedProperty\ElementValues($arSeoItem["IBLOCK_ID"],
$arSeoItem["ID"]);
$arSeoItem["IPROPERTY_VALUES"] = $ipropValues->getValues();
}    

$langing_seo_h1 = ($arSeoItem["IPROPERTY_VALUES"]["ELEMENT_PAGE_TITLE"] != "" ? $arSeoItem["IPROPERTY_VALUES"]["ELEMENT_PAGE_TITLE"] : $arSeoItem["NAME"]);
$langing_seo_title = ($arSeoItem["IPROPERTY_VALUES"]["ELEMENT_META_TITLE"] != "" ? $arSeoItem["IPROPERTY_VALUES"]["ELEMENT_META_TITLE"] : $langing_seo_h1);
$APPLICATION->SetTitle($langing_seo_h1);
$APPLICATION->AddChainItem($langing_seo_h1);

if($langing_seo_title)
    $APPLICATION->SetPageProperty("title", $langing_seo_title);

if($arSeoItem["IPROPERTY_VALUES"]["ELEMENT_META_DESCRIPTION"])
    $APPLICATION->SetPageProperty("description", $arSeoItem["IPROPERTY_VALUES"]["ELEMENT_META_DESCRIPTION"]);

if($arSeoItem["IPROPERTY_VALUES"]['ELEMENT_META_KEYWORDS'])
    $APPLICATION->SetPageProperty("keywords", $arSeoItem["IPROPERTY_VALUES"]['ELEMENT_META_KEYWORDS']);
?><?endif;?>
```

Comment: У вас нет резервных копий ? Если есть то разверните ее локально и возьмите строчку. Иначе очень затруднительно Вам помочь т.к. нужно быть немного экстрасенсом. И судя по названию компонента "element_list_1" так это копия. И я думаю где то есть компонент  оригинал element_list

Comment: Резервных копий к сожалению нет, сайт только разрабатывается. Похожего компонента тоже не нашла.

Comment: index.php  данного раздела можете скинуть? именно в корне каталога

Comment: https://yadi.sk/d/HA5QGU8l587O_Q

Comment: 107 строка в файле index  говорит о другом имени компонента. 

Там указан list_elements_1 .

Вы ошиблись в тексте когда задавали вопрос и указали имя компонента element_list_1 ?

Или у вас два файла с схожими названиями и Вы могли их перепутать

Comment: Да, я ошиблась. Всё правильно, это - list_elements_1

Comment: 8-9 строка в index немного необычная. Я не уверен но попробуйте так
"bitrix:catalog",
    "news",

Comment: нет, это именно bitrix:news, по-другому не работает. Вся проблема в той потерянной строчке, возможно там подключался какой-то файл, но я точно не помню

Comment: Мне повезло. У админа была копия файла) Если интересно, то вот какая строчка была в том файле <?$sViewElementsTemplate = ($arParams["ELEMENTS_".$upperDisplay."_TYPE_VIEW"] == "FROM_MODULE" ? $arTheme["ELEMENTS_".$upperDisplay."_TYPE_VIEW"]["VALUE"] : $arParams["ELEMENTS_".$upperDisplay."_TYPE_VIEW"]);?>

Comment: Хорошо что нашли копию.Создавайте копии перед работами. Сами видите что бывает всякое.